# Why my code isn't working?

Tags: arduino-uno, rgb-led

I wrote this code, but it doesn't work (what I want is that the program choose a random color and turn on or off an RGB led) I use transistors to turn the led strip on or off and analogWrite(pin, random(0, 255) doesn't work

```
int red = 11;
int green = 10;
int blue = 9;

int color = 1;
int stat = 1;


void setup() {
pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
pinMode(green, OUTPUT);
pinMode(blue, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  color = random(1, 3);
  stat = random(0, 1);

  if (color == 1 and stat == 0) {
    digitalWrite(red, LOW);
  }

  if (color == 1 and stat == 1) {
    digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
  }

  

  if (color == 2 and stat == 0) {
    digitalWrite(green, LOW);
  }

  if (color == 2 and stat == 1) {
    digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
  }

  

  if (color == 3 and stat == 0) {
    digitalWrite(blue, LOW);
  }

  if (color == 3 and stat == 1) {
    digitalWrite(blue, HIGH);
  }

  delay(1000);

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? "Doesn't work" could mean anything. What happens?

Comment: Nothing, nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Arduino reference: [random](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/random-numbers/random/)

In short:

> **Syntax**
>
> random(max)
>
> random(min, max)
>
> **Parameters**
>
> min: lower bound of the random value, inclusive (optional).
>
> max: upper bound of the random value, exclusive.
>
> **Returns**
>
> A random number between min and max-1. Data type: long.

Basically your first random returns values {1,2} and second one is even better {0}

Comment: So what I have to change in the code ? (I'm sorry but I don't really understand programming)

Comment: @drmarton11 you are turning the transistor on, only if there random(0,1) returns 1 and it never returns 1, it returns zeroes only as 1 is not included. If you want value 0 an 1, you have to use random(0,2) or simply random(2) as min is 0 by default

Comment: Thank you ! It works !